# Realizing rating in django

Tags: python, django

What is a better way of realizing rate field in model. Now I have this one:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...
    rate = models.(help here)

class Rating(models.Model):
    rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Or there is another way of doing this?

Comment: Is it going to be a number? Is it a number with a comma?

Comment: @LiudvikasBajarunas seems to be a float, but i confused what to put(foreignkey, float, or some relation)

Comment: Oh, you havae already rate created in Rating model. So it would probably be enough to make it a ForeignKey connected to Rating model.

Comment: And if you do a  connect Story.rate to Rating model, i think you don't need another ForeignKey in Rating.story. You can just have one ForeignKey, that's enough for a simple connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either go with a through field like this:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    rates = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=Rating)

class Rating(models.Model):
    rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

or you can do it your way with a separate model which in this case your either should remove the `rate` field from `Story` model or remove the `story` field from `Rating` model:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...
    # rate = models.(help here) No need anymore

class Rating(models.Model):
    rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and your queryset will be something like this:

```
story.rating_set.all()
```

Which will include all the ratings for the selected story instance.

Comment: Additional question, does it matter if you go one way or the other? I find myself often opting for the second one, because it gives more control over the related name (Since if you want to get the actual rating value when using a through model, you'd automatically have to access it through `story.rating_set.all()`, which (if I'm not mistaken), can not be changed the way a ForeignKey can define a `related_name`.

Comment: generally speaking, No it does not matter. But in some cases yes, based on the architecture design and project requirements.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As @Liudvikas Bajarunas said, it's enough to define `story` as a foreign key on the `Rating` model. You can access the story ratings using `rating_set`:

```py
story_ratings = story.rating_set.all()
```

See [the documentation on following relationships backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for more info.

You can combine that approach with [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) to get the average rating of a story:

```py
class Story(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return self.rating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rate'))['rate__avg']
```

Comment: how can i show the rate of story? I am using ModelViewSet and ModelSerializer

Comment: Something like the `url` field in this example ? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly

Answer (score 4):

There are some improvements that you can make:

1. It is better to refer to the user model with the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model) to refer to the user model, since you can later change your mind about it;
2. You probably want to make `user` and `story` unique together, such that a user can not make two ratings for the *same* story;
3. some databases, like PostgreSQL allow us to enforce range constraints at the database level, and thus make it more safe.

we thus can rewrite this to:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CheckConstraint, Q, UniqueConstraint

class Rating(models.Model):
    rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(check=Q(rate__range=(0, 10)), name='valid_rate'),
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'story'], name='rating_once')
        ]
```

Comment: i did that StorySerializer contains field of author which is related to another AuthorSerializer. So it brings user details. Or using get_user_model is the best practice?

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov: `get_user_model()` will here return `User` if you did not change the user model in the `settings.py`. It is however better to use `get_user_model()` over `User`, since if you later change that model, it will refer to the new one.

Comment: check=Q(rate__range=(0, 10) and validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)] do the same thing, isn't it? If yes, which one preferable and another can be deleted?

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov: no the `validators=...` are usually *not* implemented on the database layer, these are used by the forms. By adding this on the database layer as well, you can not get the database in an inconsistent state through an ORM call where you update `rate`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how do we can relate rating to class story?? and how to show the average of the story rates?

Comment: Generally speaking i can't agree with you accordingly get_user_model(). Better and safer is to use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL. This approach will prevent never ending looping with inheritance.

Comment: @SerSergious: yes, that is also advised in the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) updated it now. I also listed it as an anti-pattern (https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/refer-to-the-user-model-directly.html). But likely there are still some answers that do not refer to the user model in the correct way. Thanks! :)